# Jscript unable to get property '$o_3' of undefined or null reference CRM 2015

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2013, jscript

```
function preFilterLookup() 
{    

   1: Xrm.Page.getControl("customerid").addPreSearch(addLookupFilter);

    document.getElementById("customerid").setAttribute("defaulttype","2");
    Xrm.Page.getControl("customerid").setDefaultView("00000000-0000-0000-00AA-000010001004");
}

function addLookupFilter() 
{
    document.getElementById("customerid").setAttribute("lookuptypenames", "contact:2:Contact");
    document.getElementById("customerid").setAttribute("lookuptypes", "2");
}
```

getting an Error: unable to get property '$o_3' of undefined or null reference all items have correct ID's tried numerous variations of the code below but none will work . It seems to stem from line one, i can disable the code but its driving me crazy that i cant figure it out, any help greatly appreciated.

Comment: the code is unsupported, that's why you get errors

Comment: I assume it's a copy&paste error but the first line of the `preFilterLookup` function is not valid JavaScript

Comment: @jasonscript i highlighted the error with a one and referenced it in the comments, Guido which elements are unsupported ???

Comment: @jasonscript the first line can be valid
JonnyM the use of setAttribute to change the entities inside the lookup windows (you want to display only contacts) is unsupported.

Comment: @GuidoPreite, can you suggest another means of displaying the contacts without using setattribute ?

Comment: You could make an OnChange function on the "customerid". When they select a record If the record is different from "Contact" then clean the lookup and show an error message.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the error got introduced with the upgrade to UR1.
The below code is giving the exact same error. But only if the new (turbo) forms is switched off... In the OnLoad of the Form I call the test_onLoad function.

```
function test_onLoad() {
  var control = Xrm.Page.getControl("new_accountid").addPreSearch(function () {
    addLookupFilter();
  });
}

function addLookupFilter() 
{
  alert('Hallo');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The last line in preFilterLookup seems to indicate you are trying to default the view of the lookup.  (also Guido is right, using document.getElementById is unsupported)

If you are trying to add a custom view to the lookup and set that as the default, then you can use the

```
Xrm.Page.ui.controls.get("[tablename]").addCustomView(viewID, "[tablename]", "[viewname]", "[fetchXMLString]", "[TSAlayoutXMLstring]", true);
```